# What is the 5-digit alpha/numerical number?

Tags: global-entry

My Global Entry card has the number SC... on the lower right corner of the front of the card.  What is this number?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a three-digit security code (similar to those used on bank cards) preceded by the letters "sc" for "security code."  See, for example http://www.atnexus.com/nexuscard-activation.html.

The linked page concerns NEXUS cards, but image searches suggest that the numbering scheme for Global Entry cards is the same.